# How do I set up multiple shopping cart price rules for discount bands in Magento?

Tags: magento

I need to apply multiple discounts like this:

When the order total is less than £50:  No discount

When the order total is more than £50 but less than £100:  £5 off

When the order total is more than £100 but less than £250:  £10 off

When the order total is more than £250 but less than £500:  £25 off

When the order total is more than £500:  £50 off

I’ve tried so many different combinations but I cannot seem to get these rules to work. Please can someone give me instructions on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have seen that post: [Shopping Cart Price Rules](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them).

So the basic idea is:

1) That you go have to specify in the tab "Conditions" the **Cart Attribute** Subtotal to the price that you want.Or greater than, equal or less..

2) On the tab **Actions** just add "Fixed amount of discount" and you are set.

For your example:

1)  "Conditions" the **Cart Attribute** Subtotal equal or greater than 50
and again Subtotal equals or less than 100

2) On tab actio : Choose "Fixed amount of discount" and on Discount Amount put 10.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you vbak. I had read the document but still wasn't having any luck. It turns out that I was adding the conditions in the wrong place. I already had a condition to exclude products from a specific category. I was adding the 'equal or greater than' and 'equal or less than' rules directly underneath instead of adding the condition on a root level. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create four rules  as follows

Go to magento admin > Promotions >

1)  First rule

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
•   Subtotal  greater than  50
•   Subtotal  less than  100
Actions tab
Discount Amount * 5

2)  Second rule

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
•   Subtotal  greater than  100
•   Subtotal  less than  250
•   Actions tab
Discount Amount *  10

3)  Third Rule

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
•   Subtotal  greater than  250
•   Subtotal  less than  500
Discount Amount *  25

4)  Fourth Rule 
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
•   Subtotal  greater than  500

Discount Amount *  50

1)  Select status active
2)  Select proper website
3)  Select Customer groups
4)  No specific coupon
5)  Proper from date and to date

for more reference
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them